# How to start Activity from a class( this class extends LinearLayout ) in Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have two class , one is `public class range extends LinearLayout`.

Another one is `public class Main extends Activity`

In the **Main** , I use `MyWindowManager.createBigWindow(getApplicationContext());` to call the **range class**.

The range class:

```
public class Out_of_range extends LinearLayout {

    public static int viewWidth;
    public static int viewHeight;

    public Out_of_range(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.out_of_range, this);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.big_window_layout);
        viewWidth = view.getLayoutParams().width;
        viewHeight = view.getLayoutParams().height;


        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("loss :"+ Main.tempAddress);

        Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               //I want to start Activity when I click the button here.

                    final Intent mainintent = new Intent(getContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(mainintent);

*/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                }
            });

        }
```

And I want to start Activity from a class( this class extends LinearLayout )

I use intent , but it has error.

**The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**

Comment: Can't you override the constructor in your range class to take your String value as a parameter?
Or you can also add a String value in your range class, and access it with getter/setter.

Comment: @DamienR.:sorry...I can't understand the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make your method createBigWindow return the range object it just created

```
public static Out_of_range createBigWindow(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager(context);
    int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    if(bigWindow == null) {
        bigWindow = new Out_of_range(context);
        if(bigWindowParams == null) {
            bigWindowParams = new LayoutParams();
            bigWindowParams.x = screenWidth / 2 - Out_of_range.viewWidth / 2;
            bigWindowParams.y = screenHeight / 2 - Out_of_range.viewHeight / 2;
            bigWindowParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            bigWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
            bigWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            bigWindowParams.width = Out_of_range.viewWidth;
            bigWindowParams.height = Out_of_range.viewHeight;

        }
        windowManager.addView(bigWindow, bigWindowParams);
    }

    return bigWindow;
}
```

and then in your Out_of_range class create a method to receive the String you want to pass.

Edit:

```
//in your Out_of_range class

public void receiveStringValue(String value) {
  // do whatever you want 
}
```

and use it from your Main class after using the createBigWindow method:

```
Out_of_range range = MyWindowManager.createBigWindow(this);
range.receiveStringValue(yourString);
```

I didn't try this out but I think it's worth trying.

Edit2:

Now that you've updated your Question it's clearer: try this:

```
public class Out_of_range extends LinearLayout {

public static int viewWidth;
public static int viewHeight;

public Out_of_range(final Context context, String value) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.out_of_range, this);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.big_window_layout);
    viewWidth = view.getLayoutParams().width;
    viewHeight = view.getLayoutParams().height;


    device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device);
    device.setText("device = " + value);


    Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyWindowManager.removeBigWindow(context);
        }
    });

}
```

And in your main, do something like this:

```
MyWindowManager.createBigWindow(getApplicationContext(), "your value here");
```

Comment: But I want to receive the value from Main.class and show on the out_of_range class.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand, you have a String value in your Main class and you want to pass it to your out_of_range class so it can display it somehow, right?

Comment: I have solve the problem by using global variable, but there has another question. How to start the Main Activity in range class ??

Comment: not sure why you wanna do that but using the context you can do context.startActivity(...)

Answer (score 0):

I define the String in Main.class like `public static String tempName;`

And in range class , use `Main.tempName` to get the value.